# Can we use Jacoco for measuring code coverage of Manual Tests?

Tags: tomcat7, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

The war files are located in tomcat7/webapps/ . I have made the following changes in the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.5.201112152213</version>
    <configuration>
             <destFile>${basedir}/../../../../../../opt/tomcat7/webapps/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
             <dataFile>${basedir}/../../../../../../opt/tomcat7/webapps/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
             <outputDirectory>${basedir}/../../../../../../opt/tomcat7/webapps/coverage-reports/jacoco</outputDirectory>                                                                                                   </configuration>
            <executions>
                    <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                            <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-site</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                    <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                    </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

After building the project with the above, a folder gets created in tomcat7/webapps which contains index.html. But the same keeps on giving 0% coverage report. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation of [`prepare-agent`](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html):

> Prepares a property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent that can be passed as a VM argument to the application under test.

So the best guess that you are forgetting to use this property for JVM that executes Tomcat.